# How many packets or bytes are in the socket receive queue?

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

Calling `getsockopt` with `SO_RCVBUF` will return the allocated size of the socket receive buffer.

I am curious to know if it is possible to query for how many datagram packets (or bytes) are actually in the buffer prior to calling `recv` or `recvfrom`?  If it helps, I can settle for a Linux specific answer.  The socket in question is UDP, but I suspect it wouldn't matter for TCP.

The reason why I ask is only for testing and debugging purposes. I'm trying to validate if my call to setsocktop(SO_RCVBUF) is setting a sufficient enough size. Knowing if the receive buffer was ever close to reaching its limit would validate if a sufficient size was set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, what you are looking for is available via `ioctlsocket(FIONREAD)` and `WSAIoCtl(FIONREAD)`, which both return the full size of the complete buffered data, even when multiple datagram messages are buffered.  However, there is no equivalent on Linux.  There is `ioctl(FIONREAD)`, which only returns the size of the next buffered message.

Comment: what is your idea about using Netlink?  is there any API to find size of data in queue using netlink?

Answer (score 2):

use the [SIOCINQ](http://linux.die.net/man/7/udp) ioctl() on the socket to learn the amount of queued incoming bytes.

Similarly there's SIOCOUTQ for querying the send buffer.

Comment: This is a good start. But according to the MAN page you linked to, SIOCINQ only "Returns the  size  of the  next pending datagram in the integer in bytes, or 0 when no datagram is pending."  In other words, it tells you how many bytes the next recvfrom will return, but no additional information about the queue after that. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The sufficient size for the socket receive buffer is given by the bandwidth-delay product for the link. Bandwidth in. Bytes/second times delay in seconds = buffer size in bytes. The idea is to advertise a TCP window large enough that the sender can 'fill the pipe'. You can calculate that in advance: you don't need to tune it at runtime. Sizes towards 64k are good.

Comment: This is for UDP, not TCP. Sender tries to maintain a fixed bitrate, but can send a burst of packets that might fill up the buffer. I'm trying to figure out if the receive buffer is sufficient to handle this burst or if I need to have a dedicated thread with my own queue. Preferably not.

Comment: In that case see @nos's answer. I would definitely use the dedicated thread however.