# Winsock UDP socket receive buffer utilization

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winsock

I have established a UDP socket:

```
receiveSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
```

I then modify the socket parameters to use a larger-than-default buffer (100,000 bytes for example):

```
bufferSize = 100000;
bufferSizeLen = sizeof(bufferSize);
setsockopt(receiveSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *) &bufferSize, bufferSizeLen);
```

Later on, I'd like to query the socket to find out how much data is presently stored in the buffer (i.e. how many datagrams are waiting to be retrieved by calls to `recv()`). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `ioctlsocket()` with the `FIONREAD` option.

Comment: `FIONREAD` tells how many bytes can be read by the next `recv()`, not how many datagrams are present. You would have to call `recv()` in a loop until the buffer is empty.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Aren't you contradicting what you stated in your answer (to this same question...) here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16432235/297144

Comment: I've tested this on Windows 7, and I can confirm the value returned by `FIONREAD` is the total number of bytes in the buffer, not just the size of the first datagram. I set the `MSG_PEEK` flag on `recvfrom()` and I watched the size of the buffer increase as datagrams piled up.

Comment: @RyanEdwards: [Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573.aspx): "FIONREAD returns the amount of data that can be read in a single call to the recv function, which may not be the same as the total amount of data queued on the socket. If s is message oriented (for example, type SOCK_DGRAM), FIONREAD still returns the amount of pending data in the network buffer, however, the amount that can actually be read in a single call to the recv function is limited to the data size written in the send or sendto function call."

Comment: Yes, I agree the documentation appears to reflect reality. Your original comment _FIONREAD tells how many bytes can be read by the next recv(), not how many datagrams are present_ doesn't seem to mesh with that. What am I missing here?

Comment: @RyanEdwards What you're missing is that the next `recv()` will only receive one datagram.